# Why the texture blurred ? I need it keeps the same resolution of the source image

Tags: textures, direct3d

The source image is 1920x1200 px.

Here is my render function:

```
VOID Render()
{
    // Clear the backbuffer and the zbuffer
    g_pd3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
                     D3DCOLOR_XRGB( 0, 0, 255 ), 1.0f, 0 );

    // Begin the scene
    if( SUCCEEDED( g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene() ) )
    {

        g_pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU, D3DTADDRESS_BORDER);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV, D3DTADDRESS_BORDER);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_BORDERCOLOR, 0x000000ff);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture( 0, g_pTexture );

        // Render the vertex buffer contents
        g_pd3dDevice->SetStreamSource( 0, g_pVB, 0, sizeof( CUSTOMVERTEX ) );
        g_pd3dDevice->SetFVF( D3DFVF_CUSTOMVERTEX );
        g_pd3dDevice->DrawPrimitive( D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 2);//2 * 50 - 2 );

        // End the scene
        g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();
    }

    // Present the backbuffer contents to the display
    // show in two window
    g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
    HWND hWnd = WindowFromDC(g_hDc);
    RECT rc; rc.bottom = 600, rc.left = 100, rc.right = 600, rc.top = 100;
    //RECT rc; rc.bottom = in->height, rc.left = 0, rc.right = in->width, rc.top = 0;
    g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, &rc, hWnd, NULL );
}
```

What will be seen shows in here:
http://uploads.gamedev.net/monthly_08_2014/post-222996-0-85945200-1408348655.jpg

Why does the image the program displays look so blurred? How to set the texture to look better. The source image is 1920x1200 px !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your backbuffer isn't being resized when you resize your window?

Where you handle the windows messages for resizing the window, make sure you change your d3d properties' settings for height and width to the new ones, and reset the device.

In an old directx program of mine, my msgProc function that handles windows messages, using md3dPP as my d3d properties,

```
 case WM_SIZE:
    if( gd3dDevice )
    {
    mbTimeReset = true;
    md3dPP.BackBufferWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
    md3dPP.BackBufferHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
```

and when user is done resizing, it should send a WM_EXITSIZEMOVE message. Then, reset your device (my device is called gd3dDevice)

```
    gd3dDevice->Reset(&md3dPP);
```

Haven't done much graphics programming in years, and that was with DX9, so might be wrong/rusty.

Hope this helps though :)